# Turtle module - Detecting collisions with polygons

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm doing a small experiment with turtle, basically a small game where you can control a turtle... I have trajectory calculations already, so I can control it pretty decently!

However, I'd like to define obstacles, mostly polygons defined by a set of points.
Those would trigger collisions if the turtle hurt them (elastic collisions).

My question is...
How can I detect if I'm on the border of a polygon? Say I run straight into the middle of the hypotenuse of a triangle, how can I know this is actually a line which I cannot go through, at the right moment, in order to trigger the collision code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your polygons are defined by line segments. The turtle move is also a line segment, so you merely need to check for intersections between the turtle line segment and the list of polygon line segments.

You can probably do this for a hundred or a thousand line segments fairly quickly. Beyond that you'll need to look for smarter algorithms. eg. the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm).